# ImportError .... The specified module could not be found .. PyDev

Tags: python, eclipse, python-3.x, dll, pydev

I am running PyDev with Eclipse with Python 3.x on windows 7. I want to add a module named "Understand". I have added its directory to Python's path using `sys.path.append()`. Also, I have tried changing the environment variable `PYTHONPATH` in **windows->Preferences->PyDev->Python Interpreter->Environment**. When I check with `print(sys.path)`, it shows the path that I have given, but when I execute `import understand` it says *ImportError: DLL load failed: The specified module could not found*.

The "Understand" page instructs to *add/modify the `PYTHONPATH` environment variable to include the module location, which is `SciTools/bin/<System>/python`*. Looking into the specified folder, there is just a file named `understand.pyd`.

I also tried the same thing with Geany on Ubuntu, but the error was the same.

Comment: The module may depend on some other DLL.

Comment: how can I know on which DLL it is depending on ?

Comment: First check again the installation instructions if there is a detail you have missed. Then try to inspect the pyd file with [Dependency Walker](http://www.dependencywalker.com/)

Comment: After checking it with Dependency walker, I am getting an error _No DOS or PE signature found. This file is not a valid 32-bit or 64-bit windows module_  :(

Comment: Thanks for looking for it. They are present in SciTools\bin\pc-win32 forlder and I checked it after adding this to `PATH` in environment variable and its still showing the same error.

Comment: o mannn .. after I added directory to `PATH` , restarted Eclipse and I now I am getting the royal Eclipse error stating _A java Runtime Environment (JRE) or Java Development kit (JDK) must be available in order to run Eclipse. No Java virtual machine was found after searching the following locations: C:\eclipse\jre\javaw.exe javaw.exe in your current PATH_ So, if I change back to previous `PATH` Eclipse work and if I change to new one, Eclipse does not even open !! lol !! one after another !

Comment: aaaaahhh ... just one **semicolon** and its all working now .. it took my 1 and a hlaf day to figure that out .. Thank you sooo very much @eryksun :)

Comment: Hi, I met the same problem as you, my Python just couldn't import the understand.pyd, always import error, could you please kindly tells me about your PYTHONPATH variable? is there anything I should add to my PATH variable? Thx a lot !